# Extract data from a docx and insert into an xlsx or csv file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract data from a table that is in docx, and insert this data into a file in xslx or in csv. I chose to do it in Python, due to the ease of handling data.

Attached is the formatting of the data in the table
[image: TABLE DOCX]

This is the script I'm using to generate the tables in xlsx. But the data from table 1 and table 2 are joined.
Name, id, year, subject, start and observations.
So the ideal would be to create a spreadsheet with this data instead of creating 2 tables.
I got other settings in the code but to no avail.
That's the question, I'm not able to join these 2 tables

```
import pandas as pd 
from docx import Document

document = Document(r"test.docx")
tables = []
for index,table in enumerate(document.tables):
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            df[i][j] = cell.text
        pd.DataFrame(df).to_excel("Tabela__ "+str(index)+".xlsx")
print("Done")
```

[image: Table]

Expected configuration

[image]

So if anyone here has experience with this kind of data transformation, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Make a join of the data of the 2 tables that the script is generating. And arrive at the expected configuration, which is in the last image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test file `71433068_data.docx` can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/gremur/stackoverflow/blob/main/71433068_data.docx)

Possible solution is the following:

```
# pip install python-docx
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd
from docx import Document

document = Document("71433068_data.docx")

# group tables by two items (two tables are related with in one subject)
tbl_list_grp = [document.tables[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(document.tables), 2)]

all_data = []

for subject in tbl_list_grp:
    
    tbl_data = {}
    
    # table 1 - NAME, ID (keys are the in first column)
    for i, row in enumerate(subject[0].rows):
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
        kv = tuple(text)
        tbl_data[kv[0]]= [kv[1]] * (len(subject[1].rows)-1)

    # table 2 - YEAR, ..., OBSERVATION (keys are in the first row)
    for i, column in enumerate(subject[1].columns):

        col_cells = list((cell.text for cell in column.cells))
        tbl_data[col_cells[0]] = [_ for _ in col_cells[1:]]
        
    all_data.append(tbl_data)

# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in all_data]).reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

Returns

[image]

```
# write dataframe data to excel
df.to_excel('71433068_data.xlsx', encoding='urf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: can you please help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098471/extract-a-word-table-from-multiple-docx-files-using-python-docx